# SharePoint masterpage own navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I have created a own navigation by using html and css. I want to add this navigation to the `seattle.html masterpage`, I did this by copying the html code in the seattle.html masterpage.

My navigation appears and I can use it, but there is a little problem:

The drop down menu does not appear right, so it is a kind of transparent. You can see the problem in the image I've added. (If I add under my html code  br the navigation appears better, but this is not a solution)

It would be very great if someone can help me, because I don't know how to solve this.

[image]

**CSS CODE:**

```
<Style>

#cssmenu {
background: #0072C6;
margin: 0;
width: auto; 
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
position: relative;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

#cssmenu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after,
#cssmenu:after {
content: " ";
display: block;
font-size: 0;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
margin: 0;
-webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease;
-o-transition: color .2s ease;
transition: color .2s ease;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
top: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
max-height: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
-ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
-o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
background: #5a5a5a;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
right: auto;
left: 15px;
}


#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 0;
width: 0;
border: 4px solid transparent;
border-left-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 2;
top: 15px;
right: 15px;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
right: auto;
left: 15px;
border-left-color: transparent;
border-right-color: #5a5a5a;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: none;
color: #000000;
letter-spacing: 0;
display: block;
width: 170px;
padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,

#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
color: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
max-height: 72px;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
left: auto;
right: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
right: 100%;
left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 0;
background: #5a5a5a;
-webkit-transition: height .2s;
-moz-transition: height .2s;
-ms-transition: height .2s;
-o-transition: height .2s;
transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
padding-right: 40px;
}


#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
display: block;
content: "";
border: 6px solid transparent;
border-top-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 2;
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 16px;
top: 22px;
}


#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px 20px;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
/* Schwarz*/
background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
/* Weiß*/
border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
max-height: 72px;
position: relative;
}
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <title>CSS Menu</title>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Menu &#9776;</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Unterseite 1</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Unterseite 2</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>&emsp; &#8627 Unterseite 3</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>&emsp; &#8627 Unterseite 4</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Unterseite 5</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>&emsp; &#8627 Unterseite 6</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='http://www.google.de/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Seite 1</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Unterseite 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Unter Unterseite 1</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Unter Unterseite 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Unterseite 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Unter Unterseite 1</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Unter Unterseite 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Seite 2</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Seite 3</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/gb.png">Gästebuch</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Has anyone any idea why the code in the masterpage does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer.

There are a few things very important: If you want to display the navigation into the ribbon you have to set the background in the `ms-core-overlay` 
It is verry recommend to display the navigation not in the ribbon, you better use the class="ms-core-overlay" if you put the navigation in this div everything works fine!